# AngularJS + Hoodie: How to do a correct data flow?

Tags: angularjs, hoodie

I would like to combine AngularJS and Hoodie, but I am not sure how to do it the correct way.
Let's say I have a basic AngularJS controller

```
app.controller("c", function($scope) {
  $scope.table = [];

  $scope.onAdd = function(newEntry) {
      $scope.table.push(newEntry);
  };
});
```

After clicking on e.g.

```
<button ng-click="onAdd('test');">add</button>
```

Everything works as expected. But now I want to use Hoodie. Currently I am trying this:

```
app.controller("c", function($scope) {
  $scope.table = [];

  $scope.onAdd = function(newEntry) {
      $scope.table.push(newEntry);
  };

  hoodie.store.on('entries:add', $scope.onAdd);
});
```

and anywhere: `hoodie.store.add("entries", tmpObject);`

The `onAdd()` gets called and is inserted into the `table` array (verified in the developer console), **but** my html table (via `ng-repeat="entry in table"`) is not updated.

*First question:* Do you know why? What do I think wrong here?

*Second question:* What would be a good way to combine Hoodie and AngularJS? Would it be better to `$watch` on the table and insert items into it and store it via Hoodie after getting a change or the other way around and add a new item to the hoodie.store and then on("entries:add") do some Angular stuff?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heyho =)

First: If you update data-structure via an 'external' event(in this case hoodie), you need to trigger the Digest-Cycle e.g. [$rootScope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply);

Second: There is a [hoodie-angular-plugin](https://github.com/elmarburke/hoodie-plugin-angularjs) that is written by Elmar and me. That solved the most of your basic tasks. That would be the easiest way in this case.

Comment: Awesome! I also noticed that when triggering any other event (caused by Angular) the html table is updated properly. After reading about `$apply()` I understand why. Thanks for pointing it out.